# vue-socketio and flask-socketio

Tags: flask-socketio, vue-socket.io

I am using vue-socketio (v3.0.5) to communicate with a flask server running flask-socketio (v4.3.1). My web client can connect, but does not stay connected for long. No messaging is exchanged beyond the initial handshake. I am running the flask-socketio in verbose mode, but it doesn't give me any explanation.

Is there a version compatibility issue?

I see the following on the server:

```
89fe4114573244c4833676bd03976119: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '89fe4114573244c4833676bd03976119', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
2020-12-16 18:05:24.175 | DEBUG    | server:connect:241 - Client Connected: 89fe4114573244c4833676bd03976119
89fe4114573244c4833676bd03976119: Sending packet MESSAGE data 0
```

followed shortly by...

```
2020-12-16 18:06:24.200 | DEBUG    | server:disconnect:246 - Client Disconnected: 89fe4114573244c4833676bd03976119
2020-12-16 18:06:24.200 | DEBUG    | server:onDisconnect:78 - '89fe4114573244c4833676bd03976119'
2020-12-16 18:06:24.200 | DEBUG    | server:onDisconnect:83 - '89fe4114573244c4833676bd03976119'
89fe4114573244c4833676bd03976119: Client is gone, closing socket
```

Comment: What do the logs of the frontend console say, in the in the debug tools etc of chrome?

Comment: No client side logging in Chrome. My issue with vue-socketio is likely a version mismatch. Instead, I went with "socket.io-client": "^3.0.4", on the client side and Flask-SocketIO==5.0.0 on the server side. This combination works.

Comment: try upgrading to latest version on both vue-socketio and flask-socketio